# Printing an array of answers

Tags: objective-c

If I have this:

```
int array[3] = {1,2,3};

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    int answers = (array[i] + 1);

    NSLog(@"%d");

    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ",answers];

    self.label.text = text;
 }
```

The Nslog statement prints out all the answers. but the label only displays the last value. :( 
How do i make the label display all three answers?

Thank You.

Comment: +1 Guys please don't discourage the newbies! Give them some time to learn!

Comment: Shouldn't it be NSLog(@"%d", answer) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
int array[3] = {1,2,3};

// before you can set the label to something
self.label.text = @"answer:";

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    int answers = (array[i] + 1);

    NSLog(@"%d", answer);

    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ",answers];

    self.label.text = [self.label.text stringByAppendingString:text];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it prints only the last value is that it overwrites the previous one. Put a delay to see the other values too

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[3] = {1,2,3};
NSMutableString *mutableStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
   int answers = (array[i] + 1);
    NSLog(@"%d");

    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ",answers];
    [mutableStr appendFormat:@"%@ ",text];
}

self.label.text = text;
[mutableStr release];
```

Comment: perhaps make the string autorealease ?